# Onelogin role Rename doesn't work as expected in onelogin scim provisioning

Tags: provisioning, onelogin, scim, scim2

I build SCIM Provisioning integration with OneLogin. I use role as user groups and rule to connect roles to the SCIM Provisioning App. When I rename role, I expect to get patch command for group rename,
Something like:

```
   { "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "Replace",
            "path": "displayName",
            "value": "4f3da51f-f5a4-4458-85eb-3effb961e8ac"
        }
    ]
}
```

But instead, I see that Onelogin removes user from the existing group with old name and that's it. Is it expected and some sort of limitation?